# Garbled character in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c

Here is my test program it has Japanese character.
[image: Source code which has Japanese character]

When I debugged it it didn't show the exact characters
Instead it showed as the following screenshots
[image: Debugged console Window]
I know this is "Garbled characters" error

I tried to fix it by checking the " suppose Unicode UTX-8 for world wide character" in the Administrative  language setting but it didn't help at all

Can anyone suggest me a solution to fix this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How do the editor save the code? What encoding will the source file have?

Comment: Note, Windows is UTF-16 by default.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The editor asked me one time about the encoding and I chose Unicode UTF-8 Japanese that time. Then the error ocurred. I would like to know how can I make that happen again so I will be more careful about the encoding options